# How to add google-breakpad to iOS project?

Tags: ios, google-breakpad

I want to add google-breakpad to iOS project, unfortunately documentation of iOS client doesn't exist (or i can't find it) and my knowledge of mac/xcode/ios is really poor. How can i configure it?